# How do I compare precedence of tokens with different associativity in yacc?

Tags: yacc, operator-precedence

```
%left TOKEN1
%left TOKEN2
%right TOKEN3
```

In the above example,`TOKEN2` has higher precedence than `TOKEN1`, but what about `TOKEN3`?

Is it guaranteed that `TOKEN3` has higher precedence than `TOKEN2` or not?

Comment: You should read the docs again, specifically the precedence operator section.

Comment: @leppie ,how can I make reduce higher precedence in the dangling ELSE case?

Answer (score 1):

This declares TOKEN3 to have higher precedence that TOKEN2, but by your comments you may be misunderstanding what 'higher precedence' means to yacc/bison.

In yacc/bison, all that precedence matters for is resolving shift/reduce conflicts -- whenever there's a shift reduce conflict, the parser generator compares the precedence of the token to be shifted with the precedence of the rule to be reduced and does whichever one has the higher precedence (if they're the same, then %left favors the reduce while %right favors the shift).  That's all.  In particular, precedence has NO EFFECT on reduce/reduce conflicts.

So in the case of something like a dangling else, the precedence of the ELSE token will be compared with the precedence of the if-with-no-else production.  If the latter has higher precedence it will be reduced, which is the reverse of what most languages (and common sense) dictate.  It will also fail to work with an LALR(1) parser (though it will work with an LR(1) parser) due to the way that states get combined.

**edit**

You can follow Aymanadou's recommendation to attempt to make things work, but it won't work at all in yacc (due to it being LALR(1)) and won't really work even an LR(1) parser.  To understand why (and to see why it REALLY makes no sense), consider the input

```
if (a) if (b) c else d else e
```

Note that `d` can be an arbitratily large {}-enclosed block.  Now if you associate the first `else` with the first `if` (which is what will happen without arbitrary lookahead), when the parser gets to the second `else`, it won't have an `if` to match up with and you'll get a syntax error.  With an LALR(1) parser, because of state merging, this problem crops up even with just

```
if (a) b else c
```

In this case, if you give else lower precedence, it will reduce `if (a) b` as a an if-with-no-else statement, leaving the dangling else to cause a syntax error.

If you actually want to do what you say, you need to use a parsing method that can either do arbitrary lookahead (such as with backtracking), or can non-deterministicly parse alternatives to deal with ambiguities (such as GLR).  But doing this will generally result in a langauge that is not understandable by human readers, as the meaning of small piece of code can depend on stuff that appears much later in the code.

Comment: How to make `if(a)if(b)c else d` work as `if(a){if(b)c}else d` instead of `if(a){if(b)c else d}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set explicit precedences will may be help you

IF ELSE example

```
%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE

%nonassoc ELSE

%%
stmt   :    IF expr stmt %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE ;
       |    IF expr stmt ELSE stmt;
```